# How to plot a graph in Android?

Tags: android, graph

Hi What API I need to follow to generate graph?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896905/dynamic-graph-rendering-in-android

Comment: You could find the answer simply by googling.

Comment: check out [androidplot](http://androidplot.com)

Answer (score 6):

Checkout [aChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/), this is probably the most popular (and free) library you can use.
There is nothing native in Android to draw graphs.